# Role-Based Authentication for Dynamic Routes in Next.js - Is This Approach Correct?

Tags: next.js, routes, next-router

I'm new to Next.js, and I'm working on building a Next.js application that requires role-based authentication. To achieve this, I've implemented a **Higher-Order Component** (HOC) that checks whether a user has the necessary permissions to access certain pages.

**Here's how I've approached the issue:**

**Static Routes**: I've created a route.ts file that contains all the static route paths based on the user's access level.

**Dynamic Routes**: However, I haven't included the dynamic paths in this file because I don't know what the dynamic routes will look like. To handle this, I've added a dynamicPath key to each user object, which holds the base URL and dynamic URL.

**Handling Dynamic Routes**: To handle dynamic routes in the role-based authentication, I retrieve the params.Id from the Higher-Order component. Then, I concatenate this Id to the dynamicPath's base URL and check if it matches the dynamicPath's dynamic URL. If it's a match, the user is granted access; otherwise, they are redirected to a "permission denied" page.

While this approach seems to work fine, I'm unsure if it's the correct or recommended way to handle dynamic routes for role-based authentication in Next.js. I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find a specific approach for this scenario.

Could someone please clarify if the approach I've taken to handle dynamic routes in role-based authentication is right or wrong? If it's the wrong approach, I'd greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to handle dynamic routes with role-based authentication in Next.js. Thank you!

`Higher-Order-Component`

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter, usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { roles, rolesAccess } from "@/utils/route"; // import the roles and rolesAccess from route.ts file
import { isLoginReducer } from "@/redux/features/authSlice";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "@/components/elements/Loader";

const UseRoleHook = (Component: React.ElementType) => {
  return function ProtectedRoute({
    params,
  }: {
    params: { [key: string]: string | number };
  }) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { role, isLogin } = useSelector(
      (state: { authPersistedReducer: { role: string; isLogin: boolean } }) =>
        state.authPersistedReducer
    );

    const pathname = usePathname();
    const router = useRouter();
    const paramKey = params && Object.keys(params)[0];

    const hasPermission = false;

    useEffect(() => {
      if (!isLogin) {
        // If the user is not logged in, check if their role is included in the valid roles
        if (roles.includes(role)) {
          dispatch(isLoginReducer(true));
          router.push("/");
        } else {
          router.push("/login");
        }
      } else {
        // If the user is logged in
        if (
          // If it's a static route
          (!paramKey && !rolesAccess[role]?.path.includes(pathname)) ||
          // If it's a dynamic route
          (paramKey &&
            !rolesAccess[role]?.dynamicPaths?.some((route) => {
              return route.dynamic === route.base.concat(`[${paramKey}]`);
            }))
        ) {
          // If the user doesn't have permission for the current route, throw an error
          throw new Error("Permission Denied");
        } else {
          // If the user has permission, navigate to the current route
          router.push(pathname);
        }
      }
    }, [isLogin, role, pathname]);

    if (
      // If it's a static route and the user doesn't have permission
      (!paramKey && !rolesAccess[role]?.path.includes(pathname)) ||
      // If it's a dynamic route and the user doesn't have permission
      (paramKey &&
        !rolesAccess[role]?.dynamicPaths?.some((route) => {
          return route.dynamic === route.base.concat(`[${paramKey}]`);
        }))
    ) {
      return (
        <div className="w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
          <Loader />
        </div>
      );
    }

    // If the user has permission, render the protected component
    return <Component />;
  };
};

export default UseRoleHook;
```

`route.ts`

```
interface Role {
  path: string[];
  dynamicPaths?: [
    {
      dynamic: string;
      base: string;
    }
  ];
}

interface Roles {
  [key: string]: Role; // different key name
}
const roles: string[] = ["admin", "superAdmin", "user"];
const rolesAccess: Roles = {
  superAdmin: {
    path: ["/", "/admin", "/superadmin", "/user"],
    dynamicPaths: [{ dynamic: "/admin/test/[id]", base: "/admin/test/" }],
  },
  admin: {
    path: ["/", "/admin", "/user", "/admin/test"],
  },
  user: {
    path: ["/", "/user"],
    dynamicPaths: [{ dynamic: "/admin/test/[userId]", base: "/admin/test/" }],
  },
};

export { roles, rolesAccess };
```